# VBA To send mail using Filesearch

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

I have this code to send mail to multiple recipients using Lotus Notes. Right now I need to mention the entire file path for the attachments. My requirement is to use `FileSearch` method - mention any part of the name of the attachment within * * - so that the files get attached.

```
Sub Send()
Dim oSess As Object
    Dim oDB As Object
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim direct As Object
    Dim Var As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Annex As String
    Dim recp As Variant
    Dim cc As Variant

Dim Resp As Long

Resp = MsgBox(prompt:="Do you wish to send to the mail?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbInformation + vbDefaultButton2, Title:=AppHeader)

If Resp = vbYes Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
     For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value) = "yes" Then

    Set oSess = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set oDB = oSess.GETDATABASE("", "")
    Call oDB.OPENMAIL
    flag = True
    If Not (oDB.IsOpen) Then flag = oDB.Open("", "")

    If Not flag Then
        MsgBox "Can't open mail file: " & oDB.SERVER & " " & oDB.FILEPATH
        GoTo exit_SendAttachment
    End If
    On Error GoTo err_handler

     'Building Message
    recp = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
    cc = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
    Set oDoc = oDB.CREATEDOCUMENT
    Set oItem = oDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("BODY")
    oDoc.Form = "Memo"
    oDoc.Subject = "HI" & "-" & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
    oDoc.sendto = Split(recp, ",")
    oDoc.copyto = Split(cc, ",")
    oDoc.body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please find attached " 

     oDoc.postdate = Date
    oDoc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
        Name = Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value
        Annex = Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value
     Call oItem.EmbedObject(1454, "", Name)
    Call oItem.EmbedObject(1454, "", Annex)
      oDoc.Send False

  End If
Next cell
MsgBox prompt:="Mail Sent", Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title:=AppHeader
Exit Sub

     'Attaching DATABASE
   For Each r In Range("Fpath") '// Change to suit
    If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
      Call Send

    End If
    Next
    oDoc.visable = True
     'Sending Message

exit_SendAttachment:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSess = Nothing
    Set oDB = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set oItem = Nothing
     'Done



err_handler:
    If Err.Number = 7225 Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
    On Error GoTo exit_SendAttachment


Else

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

End If

End Sub
```

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been years since I have worked with Lotus notes. The last question that I answered on Lotus notes was way back in [July 26, 2011](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f9379b61-ffc6-491d-b36e-e9b37885ee7e/how-do-i-send-an-email-from-excel-containing-only-certain-cells-from-the-workbook?forum=exceldev#a67ce1c7-e269-40c2-8c50-bfba3cf15323) So be gentle on me if I miss any syntax. **:p**

`Application.FileSearch` method is no longer supported from XL2007+

**Reference**: [Error message when you run a macro to search for a file in an Office 2007 program: "Run-time error 5111"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920229)

In case the above link dies, here is the screenshot.

[image]

As mentioned in that link You can use the `FileSystemObject` object to recursively search directories and to find specific files. [Here is how we do that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601)

In case the above link dies, here is the code from that link.

```
'~~> COURTESY: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601
Option Explicit

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim nDirs As Long, nFiles As Long, lSize As Currency
   Dim sDir As String, sSrchString As String
   sDir = InputBox("Type the directory that you want to search for", _
                   "FileSystemObjects example", "C:\")
   sSrchString = InputBox("Type the file name that you want to search for", _
                   "FileSystemObjects example", "vb.ini")
   MousePointer = vbHourglass
   Label1.Caption = "Searching " & vbCrLf & UCase(sDir) & "..."
   lSize = FindFile(sDir, sSrchString, nDirs, nFiles)
   MousePointer = vbDefault
   MsgBox Str(nFiles) & " files found in" & Str(nDirs) & _
          " directories", vbInformation
   MsgBox "Total Size = " & lSize & " bytes"
End Sub

Private Function FindFile(ByVal sFol As String, sFile As String, _
   nDirs As Long, nFiles As Long) As Currency
   Dim tFld As Folder, tFil As File, FileName As String

   On Error GoTo Catch
   Set fld = fso.GetFolder(sFol)
   FileName = Dir(fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, sFile), vbNormal Or _
                  vbHidden Or vbSystem Or vbReadOnly)
   While Len(FileName) <> 0
      FindFile = FindFile + FileLen(fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, _
      FileName))
      nFiles = nFiles + 1
      List1.AddItem fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, FileName)  ' Load ListBox
      FileName = Dir()  ' Get next file
      DoEvents
   Wend
   Label1 = "Searching " & vbCrLf & fld.Path & "..."
   nDirs = nDirs + 1
   If fld.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
      For Each tFld In fld.SubFolders
         DoEvents
         FindFile = FindFile + FindFile(tFld.Path, sFile, nDirs, nFiles)
      Next
   End If
   Exit Function
Catch: FileName = ""
       Resume Next
End Function
```

Once you are able to select the files you can use the below code in a loop to add the attachments

```
stAttachment = "Blah Blah.Txt"
Set obAttachment = oDoc.CreateRichTextItem("stAttachment") 
Set EmbedObject = obAttachment.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", stAttachment)
```

Comment: Sid! Huge heaps of appreciation to you! That was immense and quick. I inserted an ActiveX Control List Box. Getting an error at -inline `List1.AddItem fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, FileName)`